# ng-click within an ng-repeat, not formatting values correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to AngularJS and my javascript skills aren't quite up to scratch.

I have an array of teams:

```
$scope.teams = ['Team-1', 'Team-2', 'Team-3']
```

and an ng-repeat, looping through these:

```
<span ng-repeat="team in teams">{{ $index + 1 }}: {{ team }}</span>
```

but I also want to add an ng-click to these elements, like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-click="addTeam(' {{ team | lowercase }}')">{{ team }}</span>
```

Clicking the element does add an entry to the array but it adds the value '*{{ team | lowercase }}*' rather than the intended lowercase team name. If I look at the code inspector, these values do display correctly in the elements.

i.e. *ng-click="addTeam('team-1')*, etc.

...is there something I'm missing from the ng-click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the right syntax

```
<span ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-click="addTeam(team | lowercase)">{{ team }}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct one.

```
<span ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-click="addTeam(team | lowercase)">{{ team }}</span>
```